# Remove annoying "OK"'s from the output of applescript?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to read a string using AppleScript from the command line.

I have the following script:

```
on run prompt
    set theResponse to display dialog prompt default answer ""
    --> {text:"Jen"}
    return (text of theResponse)
end run
```

Which seems to work fine but the output is "OK, hello". I want to get rid of this OK and just print a script.

## Thanks for the answers, here are some useful links related to them

Forgive my non-applescript nomenclature - I hope this is useful to people like me looking at the issue.

- [of as a property accessor](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW24)

Comment: This requests the **text** class of theResponse. You should request the **text returned** property instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display dialog` returns a **record** with keys `button returned` and `text returned`. Actually there is third key `gave up` which appears only if the parameter `giving up after` is specified

You can write

```
on run prompt
    set theResponse to display dialog prompt default answer ""
    return text returned of theResponse
end run
```

or

```
on run prompt
    set {text returned: textReturned} to display dialog prompt default answer ""
    return textReturned
end run
```

Comment: Thanks I'm avoiding going too deep on apple script because... other things to do and I'm basically using it for dialog interfaces on mac. If you don't mind me being too lazy why did `return (text of theResponse)` not error out if there was no text?

Comment: Even an empty string is text, but in this case `text of` converts the record to a list `{"OK",""}`.

Comment: Ah okay... so `text of` is like a cast that always returns {"OK", something} ?

Comment: Yes, it's called *coercion* in AppleScript. But it's a pretty unusual syntax.

Comment: Re: @Att Righ, as I sad **text of** requests **text** class (every text type value) of theResponse. theResponse in your case is a record **{button returned: "OK", text returned: "Jen"}**. Text values of this record is "OK" and "Jen". So, naturally you got the list of 2 strings **{"OK", "Jen"}**

Comment: Then if you execute script from the shell, the shell can't return the AppleScript lists like {"OK", "Jen"}, so it tries to coerce to text this list too. So the end result became "OK,Jen" (single string)

Comment: In general, in order not to create a number of unforeseen oddities, you just need to correctly request - the **text returned** property of the dialog.

Comment: @RobertKniazidis Thanks for the reply, yeah I understand the fix and it works great. What was confusing me was why the code worked at all to start with!